# Wordpress import error

Tags: import, memory, php.ini

Firstly I installed WordPress on my site, then I generate a XML file for my blog (akasujjwal.wordpress.com) transfer by using export tool. And when I try to import this XML file to the installed WordPress then I face this error:

> Sorry, there has been an error. File is empty. Please upload something
>   more substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being
>   disabled in your `php.ini` or by `post_max_size` being defined as smaller
>   than `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini`.

Why did this occur and is there any solutions for this?

I was trying to install WordPress on a site at a free host. During this I faced this error. And I was unable to install WordPress.

Comment: Explain what exactly you wanted to do and what you did. Then only add code or error messages. [File an edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/172921/edit) to your question and add more details.

Comment: You will need to increase memory limit in `php.ini`. You will have to add `memory_limit = 128M` to increase PHP memory limit.

Comment: thank for you reply sir. But may i know where i'll get php.ini file on hosting site.

Answer (score 0):

thank you everyone who give their precious time to this question, lastly I solve this problem by myself... I think this error is because of memory limit.

And I have no access to my php.ini file. So I created my own php.ini file with the following in it and added to my wp-admin folder.

memory_limit = 128M

and now its work for me !!